# How to process XML datasets?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I'm new for spark and programming language. I need some help to parse the XML files based on each tags.

Here are my small example
Input file:

```
XML File:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myfile.xsl" ?>
<bookstore specialty="novel">
  <book style="autobiography">
    <author>
      <first-name>Joe</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <award>Trenton Literary Review Honorable Mention</award>
    </author>
    <price>12</price>
  </book>
 </bookstore>

XPATH for above file:

/bookstore[@specialty="novel"]/book[@style="autobiography"]/price
/bookstore[@specialty="novel"]/book[@style="autobiography"]/author
/bookstore[@specialty="novel"]/book[@style="autobiography"]
/bookstore[@specialty="novel"]
```

Now i want to read the xpath and parse the files based on each tags (bookstore.txt, book.txt, author.txt)

Bookstore.txt:

```
UUID= 1233455 (onfly have to create)
specialty="novel"
```

Book.txt:

```
UUID= 1233455 (coming from bookstore)
style="autobiography"
<price>12</price>
```

Author.txt:

```
UUID= 9876534(onfly generate and link to book file)
<first-name>Joe</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <award>Trenton Literary Review Honorable Mention</award>
```

Please can some one help me about it.

Thank you in Advance..

Comment: Please, read the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You should first try to solve the problem yourself, show that you've tried to search and **provide any code that you have so far**. You cannot just state a problem and ask for a ready to use solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spark SQL and the [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) module which is:

> A library for parsing and querying XML data with Apache Spark, for Spark SQL and DataFrames.